# php echo emoji become question mark, but paste at here are fine

Tags: php, emoji

this string i m copy from mysql and post at here automatically become emoji icon, 小霸王

but, when i use php to echo this string, become 小霸王?.

why?

this is how i select from mysql code

```
<?php
$Recordset1 = new WA_MySQLi_RS("Recordset1",$locahost,0);  
$Recordset1->setQuery('SET character set utf8mb4');
$Recordset1->setQuery('SET NAMES utf8mb4');  
$Recordset1->setQuery(  
"   
SELECT tbl_trans.trans_username,  
    Sum(Case When tbl_trans.trans_type <> 'REWARD' AND   tbl_trans.trans_winlose <> 'QB' then  
         trans_winloseamount Else 0 End) BETHOST,  
    Sum(Case When tbl_trans.trans_winlose = 'QB'  then  
         trans_winloseamount Else 0 End) QB,   
     Sum(Case When tbl_trans.trans_type = 'REWARD'  then  
         trans_winloseamount Else 0 End) REWARD ,  
    Sum(Case When tbl_trans.trans_type <> '' then  
         trans_winloseamount Else 0 End) NETWINLOSE  
 FROM tbl_trans   
 WHERE (trans_datetime >  '".$datefrom. " 14:00:00' AND trans_datetime <   '".$dateto." 12:00:00')  
 GROUP BY trans_username");  

$Recordset1->execute();  
?>`
```

and .php html file with `<meta charset='utf-8'>`

and i have tried `header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8')`

and
`ALTER DATABASE wxbot_backup CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tbl_trans CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tbl_trans charset=utf8mb4, MODIFY COLUMN trans_username VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`

1 more thing i can't set this to utf8mb4

`mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%'; SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
-----+
| Variable_name            | Value
     |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
-----+
| character_set_client     | gbk
     |
| character_set_connection | gbk
     |
| character_set_database   | utf8
     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary
     |
| character_set_results    | gbk
     |
| character_set_server     | utf8
     |
| character_set_system     | utf8
     |
| character_sets_dir       | C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\share\chars
ets\ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
-----+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

and how to set `character_set_client` to utrfmb4 ? i m using window 7

**what is the problem?**

**UPDATE**
[image]

at mysql is look like this

Comment: @DainisAbols that's not helpful at all...

Comment: For MySQL, you'll need to use `utf8mb4` instead of `utf8` - set the connection-charset, don't just run `SET NAMES utf8mb4`

Comment: You should add `$Recordset1->setQuery('SET character set utf8mb4'); ` in addition to `SET NAMES`. Have the strings been entered via the connection in PHP, or manually via phpMyAdmin? Are the collation settings of the table/columns correctly set to utf8mb4 as well?

Comment: @Connum yes i did , updated question

Comment: @Connum it's through PHP connection, not phpMyadmin

Comment: So have you tried `SET character set utf8mb4` as I suggested?

Comment: @Connum by default i had tried utfmb4, but can't work i only change it to utf8, utfmb4 also can't work, i had tried `SET character set utf8mb4`

Comment: 對不起, I didn't understand your last reply. The utf8 range in MySQL does not support emojis, so you have to use utf8mb4. Again: It's not enough to use only `SET NAMES`, you also have to use `SET character set`...

Comment: @Connum Yes, i had tried, update the php source code above, please have a look, it does not work

Answer (score 3):

Problem solve with PHP code

`$locahost->set_charset('utf8mb4');`